# Error with section numeration while using abntex

Tags: sectioning, abnt

I am using `abntex2` to write my document and, for some reason unknown to me, the first section is marked with 0.1, instead of 1, the second, with 0.2 instead of 2 and so on. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[brazil,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand\contentsname{Índice}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE SANTA CATARINA

CENTRO TECNOLÓGICO 

DEPARTAMENTO DE ENGENHARIA DO CONHECIMENTO

\vspace{0.3cm}

Franciele Daltoé

\vspace{8.2cm}

\begin{Large}
    \textbf{Avaliação e Aprendizagem: \\ métodos diferenciados de avaliação na disciplina de matemática}
\end{Large}

\vspace{6.7cm}

Florianópolis

2015

\end{center}

\newpage

%\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE SANTA CATARINA

CENTRO TECNOLÓGICO 

DEPARTAMENTO DE ENGENHARIA DO CONHECIMENTO

\vspace{0.3cm}

Franciele Daltoé

\vspace{6.5cm}
\begin{Large}
    \textbf{Avaliação e Aprendizagem: \\ métodos diferenciados de avaliação na disciplina de matemática}
\end{Large}
\end{center}

\begin{flushright}

\vspace{1cm}

\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{Projeto apresentado ao Curso de Licenciatura em Matemática como requisito para conclusão da disciplina Projetos Interdisciplinares I.}

\end{flushright}

\vspace{5.2cm}

\begin{center}

Florianópolis 

2015
\end{center}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introdução}

\end{document}
```

There is a lot more text below, but that already shows what the problem is. What could be the error in the code?

Comment: Welcome! Please always post complete examples which can compile and which are minimal i.e. as much and no more code than is needed. This is neither minimal nor complete! However `\chapter{}` should be your top-level document division with this class - not `\section{}`.

Answer (score 3):

The class is designed for something like a book or report rather than an article. Hence, it is designed for documents which are divided into chapters:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter and section]

Answer (score 1):

The `abntex2` class supports chapter, but it's easy to fool this mechanism:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution depending on the application is to provide the `article` option to the class. As described in the manual, the `article` option makes `\section` the top division of the document (rather makes it like `\chapter` but when `article` is enabled, `\chapter` should not be used), it also disables page breaks between chapters.

```
\documentclass[article]{abntex2}

\begin{document}
\textual
\section{First section}
Text.

\section{Second section}
Text.
\end{document}
```

[image]