# Change page numbering of Chapter, Section, etc. (Memoir)

Tags: sectioning, abntex2

I'm using `abntex2` as my document class, which extends the Memoir package. In this numbering scheme, the default is that the first section, subsections etc be 0.1, 0.2, etc.

How can I change that, so that my section, subsection etc behaves as 1.1, 1.2, etc., as is in article?

MWE:

```tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{abntex2} % Use A4 paper with a 12pt font size - different paper sizes will require manual recalculation of page margins and border positions

%%%%%%%%%%%% ----------- PACOTES/PACKAGES ----------- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{morefloats}         % permite mais floats
\usepackage{parskip}            % espaçamento entre os parágrafos


\usepackage[brazil]{babel}      % idiomas
\usepackage{listings}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={\@title}, 
  pdfauthor={\@author},
  pdfsubject={Modelo de artigo científico com abnTeX2},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
  pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{atigo científico}, 
  colorlinks=true,              % false: boxed links; true: colored links
  linkcolor=blue,           % color of internal links
  citecolor=blue,               % color of links to bibliography
  filecolor=magenta,            % color of file links
  urlcolor=blue,
  bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT
% ---

\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
  \ifcase #1 %
  Nenhuma citação no texto.%
  \or
  Citado na página #2.%
  \else
  Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
  \fi}%
% ---
% O tamanho do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% Espaçamento simples
\SingleSpacing


%%%%%% HEADERS  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{nicematrix} % <<<< added for an easy  table
\usepackage[datesep=/,useregional=numeric]{datetime2} %<<<<< added format date
\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{% to use only in the first page
  \fancyhf{}% Clear default headers and footers
  \input{header-footer.tex}
}%%%%%% firstpagestyle ends

\begin{document}
% Seleciona o idioma do documento (conforme pacotes do babel)
%\selectlanguage{english}
\selectlanguage{brazil}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 


\section{Secção numérica}
\lipsum[0]
\section{Secção numérica 2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: You didn't use `\chapter` proipr to your first `\section`, hence the "0". Sections are numbered within their corrensponding chapter using the scheme `chapter number.section number`.

Comment: How could I not use chapter and still have "1 [section-title]" be my \section{section-title}?

Comment: According to the manual, there is the `article` option. Adding it probably results in the expected output.

Comment: You can also manually increase the `chapter` counter by issuing `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` prior to your `\section`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278800/134144

Comment: It works that way chsk.

And, reading your link, leandriis, in fact it's a duplicate. I didn't find this question, when I was consulting stack overflow, before posting. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand the `abntex2` manual as I am a monoglot English speaker. However I was the original developer of `memoir`.

In `memoir` the assumption is that `\chapter` commands come before `\section` commands like in the `book` and `report` classes. `memoir` has an `article` option whereby the output looks like an `article`; a `\chapter` is typeset like an article's `\section`, a `\section` is typeset like an aericle's  \subsection`, and so on. I did this because sometimes people wanted to convert a` report`to an`article`or vice-versa, so`memoir` accomplishes this through the class option without having to change the body of the document.

Try something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass[article]{abntex2}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter like a section}
\section{A section like a subsection}
\subsection{A subsection like a subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Read the `abntex2` manual to see what it says about this.

Comment: Thank you. The article option was available on abntex2. And, it formated sections as 1 right out of bat.